# Probability of two events occurring in same time period across time-series data

Tags: probability, time-series

I haven't studied probability mathematics for a long time. However, some time-series data came my way and I'm trying to ascertain the likelihood of two events happening during the same time intervals. For example:

- 100 time series units (days)
- Event A happens on 70 of the days
- Event B happens on 5 of the days
- If an event happens on a given day, it won't happen again that same day. So 70 of the 100 days will have an event A. Neither can double up in other words.
- Assume likelihoods are random within the 100 time units and both events are independent

Q: What is the probability that all event B occurrences are on days where event A also happens?

I think this is where I want to take the inverse and look at the 1 - P(B in days A not happen), i.e., the other 30.

I apologize if this is trivial. Examples I've found are all draw with/without replace style ones and I don't know if that applies here. I did [find this here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046492/how-likely-are-two-events-to-occur-at-the-same-time) but I'm wary of this being overly complicated in comparison to my case. Again, for the purposes of explanation, I'm assuming the events are independent, though in reality there's likely a positive correlation between them.

Comment: $\frac{70}{100}\frac{69}{99}\frac{68}{98}\frac{67}{97}\frac{66}{96}$

Comment: Someone just downvoted this good question (and probably my answer too). I wonder why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{100}5$ sets of 5 days that could be the event B days. Of these, $\binom{70}5$ are subsets of the event A days. If all $\binom{100}5$ possible sets are equally likely, then the desired probability is $\binom{70}5/{\binom{100}5}$.

This is equal to $\frac{70}{100}\frac{69}{99}\frac{68}{98}\frac{67}{97}\frac{66}{96}$, which is approximated by Ethan's answer $\left(\frac{70}{100}\right)^5$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Dying old brain cells are springing to life seeing this.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is as independent as you claim then the probability that any particular $B$ occurs when there's an $A$ is $70/100$. Then the probability that they all occur on $A$ days is $0.7^5 \approx 0.16807$.

That assumes that multiple $A$s can happen on the same day, with a similar assumption for the $B$s - "sampling with replacement". The calculation with the opposite assumption is a little trickier. The answer is probably not much different.

**Edit** in response to comment.

OK so the $A$s come on $70$ of the $100$ days - it doesn't matter which. Then the probability that the first $B$ is on an $A$ day is $70/100$. Now that day can't have another $B$, so the probability that the second $B$ is on an $A$ day is $69/99$. And so on. The probability that all the $B$s are on $A$ days is
$$
\frac{70}{100}
\frac{69}{99}
\frac{68}{98}
\frac{67}{97}
\frac{66}{96} \approx
0.16076  .
$$

Comment: Apologies -- In this case if an event occurs on a given day, it won't happen again that same day. I'll edit the question to reflect that.